# How to get set difference of dataframes based on column labels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I'd like to get the set differences of pandas dataframes `df_a` und `df_b` based on column labels. Consider `df_a`

```
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=[0.1, 0.2, 0.6],
    data=[[59, 10, 50]],
)
df_a
```

```
    0.1     0.2     0.6
0   59      10      50
```

and `df_b`

```
df_b = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=intervals_b,
    data=[[59, 20, 50]],
)
```

```
    0.1     0.4     0.6
0   59      20      50
```

. How do I get the expected set difference w.r.t. `df_a`

```
    0.2
0   10
```

and w.r.t. `df_b`

```
    0.4
0   20
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the setdiff1d available in numpy library.

For a dif b:

```
import numpy

df_a_b = pd.DataFrame(columns=np.setdiff1d(df_a.columns, df_b.columns),data=df_a[np.setdiff1d(df_a.columns, df_b.columns)])

print(df_a_b)
    0.2
0   10
```

And the pretty much the same for b dif a:

```
df_b_a = pd.DataFrame(columns=np.setdiff1d(df_b.columns, df_a.columns),data=df_b[np.setdiff1d(df_b.columns, df_a.columns)])

print(df_b_a)
    0.4
0   20
```